# How to make `[key: string]: string` appear in NestJS Swagger generation

Tags: typescript, swagger, nestjs

I have the following class that represents a response:

```js
class SomeResponse {
  property1?: string;
  [key: string]: string
}
```

I want to use the nest-cli to generate the correct swagger documentation for this response.
It works for all my other `simpler` properties i.e. `property1` shows correctly in the swagger.
I also tried annotating directly with:

```js
class SomeResponse {
  property1?: string;
  @ApiProperty()
  [key: string]: string
}
```

but this is not allowed, as this gives: `error TS1206: Decorators are not valid here.`

Is there a way to annotate manually or with the nest-cli constructions like `[key: string]: string`?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems decorators cannot be attached to index signatures. You can alternatively use `additionalProperties` (see [here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/dictionaries/)) but it will make a nested object.

```
class SomeResponse {
  @ApiProperty({ type: 'object', additionalProperties: { type: 'string' } })
  data: Record<string, string>;
}
```

This will be extracted as the following.

```
{
  "data": {
    "additionalProp1": "string",
    "additionalProp2": "string",
    "additionalProp3": "string"
  }
}
```